Global associative array (hash) in the older bash-4
The following script works as expected for me on FreeBSD using bash-5:
function a {
    declare -gA Seen

    if [[ -v Seen[$1] ]]
    then
        echo "Saw $1 already"
        return
    fi

    Seen[$1]=''
}

a a
a a
a b
a a
a b

Yielding the output of:
Saw a already
Saw a already
Saw b already

On RHEL7, however, where bash is older (4.2), the repeated argument is never recognized as already seen -- as if the Seen-array is recreated each time the function is invoked. Moving the declare-line outside of the function -- into global scope -- does not help.
Is there a work-around, perhaps? Some way for a function to persist its state between invocations (within the same bash-process)?

The array is fine. However, -v didn't support array references until bash 4.3. You'll need some other way to test if $1 is already an index of Seen.

See Easiest way to check for an index or a key in an array? for ways to test if array indexes exist in versions of Bash older than 4.3.

The if [ -v 'Seen[$1]' ] should be working, but it does not. The if [ ${Seen[$1]:=0} -ne 0 ] works...

For what you appear to be trying to do, i.e. check if a string has been seen previously or not, I'd just post-increment the array value every time the index is tested while simultaneously testing if the value is non-zero before the post-increment occurs as, if so, that'd mean it had been incremented previously:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

a() {
    declare -gA Seen

    if (( Seen[$1]++ ))
    then
        echo "Saw $1 already"
    fi
}

a a
a a
a b
a a
a b


$ ./tst.sh
Saw a already
Saw a already
Saw b already


Another take -
a() {
  declare -gA Seen
  if [[ -n "${Seen[$1]}" ]]
  then echo "Saw $1 already"
  else Seen[$1]=1
  fi
}

This isn't any better than Ed's but I had already typed and tested. :)

We begin most of our scripts with set -u here. –
Mikhail T.

Excellent! I generally do the same. Also, easy to accommodate.
I still recommend Ed's, but to address your concern:
$: set -u
$: declare -gA Seen
$: a() {
>   if [[ -n "${Seen[$1]:-}" ]] # set -u safe
>   then echo "Saw $1 already"
>   else Seen[$1]=1
>   fi
> }
$: a a
$: a a
Saw a already


We begin most of our scripts with set -u here.

@MikhailT., BashFAQ/112 (What are the advantages and disadvantages of using set -u (or set -o nounset)?) may be of use or interest.
